# Formula to determine SQL Pool Distribution type

Tags: data-warehouse, azure-synapse, azure-synapse-analytics

Is there a formula to determine SQL Pool Distribution type (HASH, REPLICATE, or ROUND ROBIN) before we create the table? We have the data in staging tables so we want to examine that data and determine which distribution type we need for the final table.

I was thinking the following algorithm would work:
If the Primary Key Column data has over 40 distinct values and the rows for each distinct value is over 100,000 rows, then use HASH distribution based on the Primary key column. Otherwise use REPLICATE distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally there is no fixed formula to determine the type of distribution as it depends on multiple factors like amount of data, the columns used in join conditions/logics , distinct values,usage of data etc.
And the distribution of table might also need change in future based on some of the above factors to avoid skewness.

the below link explains in details :
https://rajanieshkaushikk.com/2020/09/09/how-to-choose-right-data-distribution-strategy-for-azure-synapse/